# how can class which inherits see same value of data member which belongs to the inherited class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

In a class which inherits I’m unable to get the same value of a non static data member which belongs to the class being inherited.

I tried looking around on here for similar instances to my problem I found a few but due to my weak knowledge about classes/inheritance I’m having difficulty properly interpreting responses.

I’ll attempt to give an example which I created so that I may have a better chance grasping future explanations/methods.

//Class #1 header file:

```
class customer {
  public:
    String customer_bike = “Honda”;

    customer();
    void what_bike()
}
```

//Class #1 source file:

```
#include “customer.h”

customer:: customer(){

}

void customer::what_bike(){

Serial.print(“customer owns a “);
Serial.println(customer_bike);
}
```

//Class #2 header file:

```
#include “customer.h”

class dealer : public customer {
  public:
    dealer();
    customer customer;
    void sell_ducati();
}
```

//Class #2 source file:

```
#include “dealer.h”

dealer::dealer(){

}

void dealer::sell_ducati(){
  customer.customer_bike = “Ducati”;
}
```

//main program:

```
#include “customer.h”
#include “dealer.h”

customer customer;
dealer dealer;

Void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200);

}

Void loop(){
customer.what_bike();
delay(2000);

dealer.sell_ducati();

customer.what_bike();

while(1);
}
```

How can I modify data member in one instance and have it reflect in another instance?
If it can’t be done what method is a good choice?

I would like code to maintain some ease of portability for example from cpp to c in short I don’t want to use anything from cpp standard library

Update:
Got my issue ironed out now I’m wondering how to have the #3 class read the same value “customer_bike” is modified.

Class #3 header file:

#include “customer.h”

```
class phone  : public customer{
  public:
    phone();
    void broadcast();
  
}
```

//Class #3 source file:

```
#include “phone.h”

phone::phone(){

}

void phone::broadcast(){
  //broadcast here
  Serial.print(“hello world I bought a “);
  Serial.println(customer.customer_bike);  // << I want this to print Ducati
}
```

//updated main program:

```
#include “phone.h”
#include “dealer.h”


phone phone;
dealer dealer;

Void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200);

}

Void loop(){
dealer.customer.what_bike();
delay(2000);

dealer.sell_ducati();

dealer.customer.what_bike();

phone.broadcast();

while(1);
}
```

Comment: The seemingly simple solution is to remove `customer customer;` from `class dealer`. I'm guessing that is there because of some misunderstanding you have about inheritance.

Comment: Class Dealer is both a Customer, and owns another Customer. Dealer should probably not be a Customer, nor own a Customer. To make Dealer not a customer, change `class Dealer : public Customer` to just `class Dealer`. To make it not own a Customer, remove `Customer customer;` from it. You probably want `sell_ducati()` to change another customer, so pass in the customer as a reference (not a copy, we do not want to duplicate the customer!). Then, when calling the function, pass in the customer. Alternatively pass the customer in the constructor and store the reference, or keep it global.

Comment: I don’t wish to pass any values I would like to modify the data member customer_bike directly from dealer.

Comment: Ok, if you want Dealer to own a customer and modify the customer it owns, then it is already doing that, but it is currently displaying a different customer (the one that is not owned by the dealer). So in the main program, instead of calling `customer.what_bike();` call `dealer.customer.what_bike();`. This calls the function on the customer the dealer owns instead of the one declared in the main program.

Comment: Please see my update